# Why does the result of `Subclass new superclass` differ from `Subclass superclass`?

Tags: inheritance, smalltalk, superclass, super, self

Consider the following code:

```
Object subclass: Two []
Two subclass: Three [
    superclass [^super class]
]
Three subclass: Five []
```

Why does `Five new superclass` return `Five` while `Five superclass` returns `Three`?

From what I read in the source code of the Object class in both Dolphin Smalltalk and GNU Smalltalk, the `class` uses `self` which is why `Five new superclass` returns `Five`. I do not understand why `Five superclass` returns `Three`, however.

---

I'm using an [online version](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_smalltalk_online.php) of the GNU Smalltalk interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's depict the hierarchy

```
Object
  Two
    Three
      Five
```

Also, we have the (instance side) method

```
Three >> superclass
  ^super class
```

First of all, let's recall that `Five superclass` is `Three` just because `Five` is a direct subclass of `Three` (nothing special here).

Now let's see why `Five new superclass` answers with `Five` instead. For this we need to closely analyze the `superclass` method above.

Since the message `#class` is implemented at the top of the hierarchy (every object knows how to answer its `class`), the method at `Three` just refers to the inherited `class` method implemented in `Object`. Hence, `Three >> superclass` is essentially equivalent to `class` (it does nothing but invoking the inherited method `class` which it already got "for free"). Finally, since `Five` inherits from `Three`, when we send `superclass` to any of its instances (`Five new superclass`), we get the same we would have gotten for any instance of `Three` (inheritance again), which is the `class` of the instance which receives the message, `Five` in this case.

What might be confusing here is the use of `super` in `Three >> superclass`. But in this case `super` is entirely equivalent to `self`. It wouldn't have been, had `Three` implemented `class` in a way different from the one inherited from `Object` (which it didn't). So in fact, the method is equivalent to

```
Three >> superclass
  ^self class
```

meaning that for instances and subinstances of `Three` asking their `superclass` is the same as asking for their `class`.

Another piece of confusion comes from the tricky selector chosen: `superclass`. By default, `superclass` is a message understood by classes, not instances. However, the trick here is to implement the same selector on the instance side of the class to bring confusion on purpose (and test your orientation). This is confusing because when we see `superclass` our brains "automatically" connect with *the class that is above me*. But that is only true if you are speaking to the class, not to any of its instances.

To further uncover the trick, let's rename the selector to something less special

```
Three >> foo
  ^super class
```

and then try `Five new foo`, which will answer `Five` just because `Five new` is an instance of `Five`.

Comment: What a wonderful answer! I guess that "*By default, `superclass` is a message understood by classes, not instances.*" is what I missed. Thanks a lot :)